# Ignore property on model property

Tags: dapper, dapper-rainbow, dapper-extensions

How can I ignore a property on my model using dapper/dapper extensions/dapper rainbow or any

of those dapper libraries?

Comment: For Insert<Person>(person). person has kind of computed property. Which does not belong to the database.

Comment: Since non of the answers below provide a solution for a Dapper.Rainbow based project, I am adding this comment. Dapper Rainbow has an IgnoreProperty Attribute that can be used.  Your POCO class has to reference Dapper.Rainbow.{SQL} and then you can use [IgnoreProperty(true)] for properties that you wish to exclude

Comment: Related for Dapper.Contrib: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57673107/5779732

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dapper creator Sam Saffron has addressed this requirement in response to another SO user's questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967734/325521). Check it out.

Also, if you want to use the [Dapper Extensions library](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) that Sam has mentioned in his answer, you can get it from Github or via Nuget.

Here's an example of ignoring properties from the Library's [Test Project](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/tree/master/DapperExtensions.Test/Data).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DapperExtensions.Mapper;

namespace DapperExtensions.Test.Data
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Phone> Phones { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Phone
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonMapper : ClassMapper<Person>
    {
        public PersonMapper()
        {
            Table("Person");
            Map(m => m.Phones).Ignore();
            AutoMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where/When do you instantiate the PersonMapper class ? Is dapper extensions looking for Mapper class by taking the entityname + "Mapper" string and trying to instantiate it?

Comment: Yes, I believe the AutoMapper feature of Dapper Extensions looks for singular entity name + "Mapper" suffix to automap fields to ignore, fields with different names etc. In other words, I think (haven't tried it) you should be ok with just defining this PersonMapper class and ignoring the fields you want to ignore from the POCO. See the documentation here: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/AutoClassMapper

Comment: Fine it worked for me. My XXXMapper class has the same namespace.

Answer (score 31):

Dapper.Contrib has built-in support for marking a column as computed: [add ComputedAttribute to allow support for computed columns on Insert](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/67026a0dd7468dbfc5a0dd21d9918c1db3be5290).  Here's how it works:

```
class MyModel
{
  public string Property1 { get; set; }

  [Computed]
  public int ComputedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Properties marked with the `Computed` attribute will be ignored on inserts.

Comment: There is also `[Write(false)]` attribute. Can anyone tell what is the difference between `[Computed]` and `[Write(false)]`?

Comment: @vaheeds my best guess is that they were added at different times by different people who may not have been aware of the other.  I added the `Computed` attribute and wasn't aware of any `Write` attribute at the time.

Comment: They mean something different in my opinion - `[Computed]` means "this column is in the database but is a [Computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017)" but `[Write(false)]` means "this column is not in the database"

Comment: For details about `[Write(false)]` and `[Computed]`, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57673107/5779732) question.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I used [**`Dapper.Contrib`**](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib#special-attributes). 
Using `[Write(false)]` attribute on any property should solve the problem.
Some also suggest using `[Computed]` attribute.

```
public class Person
{        
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Write(false)]
    public IEnumerable<Email> Emails { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can design a base class without the computed property and use that for your inserts.

```
  class BasePerson
    {
      public String Name {get;set;}
    }

    class Person: BasePerson
    {
     public String ComputedProperty {get;set;}
    }

    Insert<BasePerson>(person);
```

Answer (score 5):

For those not wanting to include DapperExtensions, `DatabaseGenerated` from the standard `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` can be used also.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

Comment: This solution wont works with Dapper 1.50.2, on .NET CORE

Comment: This didn't work for Insert/Update in Dapper.Contrib

Comment: Using standard annotations as opposed to custom attributes should be the preferred choice for Dapper.Contrib