# Use Dapper.Contrib Update, with classes that have special helper properties

Tags: sql-update, code-first, dapper, dapper-contrib

I am new to `Dapper` and `Dapper.Contrib`. There is a class like this and there is a table in database with the same name:

```
public class Ware
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short UnitID { get; set; }
    public short TypeID { get; set; }
    public int CableCodeID { get; set; }
    public string Tag1 { get; set; }
    public string Tag2 { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
    public decimal Stock { get; set; } //this is not in database. this is helper
    public string UnitCaption { get; set; } //this is not in database. this is helper
    public string TypeCaption { get; set; } //this is not in database. this is helper
    public string FullCaption //this is not in database. this is helper
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{ID} {Name}";
        }
    }
}
```

I need to Update a whole list of this class to database. I use:

```
conection.Update(myList); // myList is List<Ware>
```

But it has an error when it run's:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'Stock'.'
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'UnitCaption'.'
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'TypeCaption'.'
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'FullCaption'.'
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26766350/1559611), Dapper.Contrib has an option to mark the property as Computed and thus ignore it

Comment: There is also `[Write(true/false)]` attribute. Can you explain what is the difference between `[Computed]` and `[Write(true/false)]`?

Comment: What you need to ignore is `[Computed]`, other one will take care whether property can be updated or not (true / false), as values are sent to the database for DML

Comment: from https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib `[Write(true/false)]` - this property is (not) writeable `[Computed]` - this property is computed and should not be part of updates. I have an extra field in my class that I don't need in DB, what should I use?

Comment: In my view you have misunderstood the working of the APIs provided , since the `[Computed]` is meant for the Helper properties that you are calculating, nonetheless, please try using code, which ever works for your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the code from `Dapper.Contrib` source code:

**Computed**

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class ComputedAttribute : Attribute { }
```

**Usage of Computed in code:**

```
private static List<PropertyInfo> ComputedPropertiesCache(Type type)
{
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> pi;
            if (ComputedProperties.TryGetValue(type.TypeHandle, out pi))
            {
                return pi.ToList();
            }

            var computedProperties = TypePropertiesCache(type).Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(a => a is ComputedAttribute)).ToList();

            ComputedProperties[type.TypeHandle] = computedProperties;
            return computedProperties;
}
```

**Now `Insert<T>` and `Update<T>` has following code:**

```
var computedProperties = ComputedPropertiesCache(type);

var allPropertiesExceptKeyAndComputed = allProperties.Except(keyProperties.Union(computedProperties)).ToList();
```

Now `allPropertiesExceptKeyAndComputed` is processed in the code further.

**WriteAttribute**

```
 public class WriteAttribute : Attribute
 {
    public WriteAttribute(bool write)
    {
       Write = write;
    }
    public bool Write { get; }
}
```

**Usage of IsWriteable in code:**

```
 private static List<PropertyInfo> TypePropertiesCache(Type type)
 {
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> pis;
    if (TypeProperties.TryGetValue(type.TypeHandle, out pis))
    {
       return pis.ToList();
    }

    var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(IsWriteable).ToArray();
    TypeProperties[type.TypeHandle] = properties;
    return properties.ToList();
 }

 private static bool IsWriteable(PropertyInfo pi)
 {
     var attributes = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WriteAttribute), false).AsList();
     if (attributes.Count != 1) return true;

     var writeAttribute = (WriteAttribute)attributes[0];
     return writeAttribute.Write;
 }
```

Now notice the function `ComputedPropertiesCache` pasted above for **Computed** it calls the method `TypePropertiesCache`, thus what would happen is, it will exclude both the properties (`Write("false")` and `Computed`), however `Write` attribute is meant for excluding the Type property from Caching, which is creates using `ConcurrentDictionary`, Its `Computed`, which is ideally meant for your use case. Hope it helps as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I get it know.