# Dapper ignore property runtime

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, dapper-contrib

Is there a way to ignore property from being mapped in runtime. Because I don't know if database has specific column and I have to check it before doing insert. If database doesn't have column then I want to ignore this one specific property.

UPDATE:

Here's my insert code

```
    public static void Insert(string connectionString, T entity)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            connection.Insert(entity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but in my case it is more risky to write inserts manually. I need to ignore one property sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

That `Insert` method is part of [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib), not Dapper itself. As the Readme for that library explains, you can use the `[Write(false)]` attribute to specify that a property isn't writeable, eg :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID {get;set;}

    public DateTime Created{get;set;}

    [Write(false)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate =>Created.Date;

}
```

The source code shows that Dapper.Contrib simply [ignores properties that aren't writable](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L128) :

```
var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(IsWriteable).ToArray();
```

Dapper is a microORM, it doesn't offer the mapping features found in full ORMs like EF or NHibernate. Dapper.Contrib adds some helper methods and very basic mapping through 5 atrributes:

- `[Table("Tablename")]` to specify the table name
- `[Key]` to mark an auto-generated key field
- `[ExplicitKey]` to mark a field that isn't generated automatically
- `[Write(true/false)]` to mark (non)writable properties
- `[Computed]` to mark calculated properties.

There's no way to specify a column name for example

Comment: But it means what I should you reflection to change [Write(true)] into [Write(false)] in runtime?

Comment: You asked how to exclude a property, not detect dynamically whether it exists and ignore it. Even full featured ORMs don't do that. If you use an ORM like EF or NH with a table that's missing a field you'll get an error. To do what you ask with EF you'd have to use [Fluent configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties#fluent-api), check the database schema on startup and add an `Ignore()` to the column config if you didn't find it. That's not what Dapper is for

Comment: @AmitJoshi Computed is ignored on updates only. Write means the property is ignored completely. If you check the source code you'll see that computed properties are handled  while non-writeable properties are ignored completely

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I did further research and updated my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57673976/5779732) accordingly. `Computed` attribute will also ignore the property while both `INSERT` as well as `UPDATE`. Please have a look and suggest if my tests were incorrect.