# Is it possible to ignore non-primitive types when adding a list to DynamicParameters.AddTable() using Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I can create a `DataTable`, and populate it with data from my list of objects, in order to use the values in my Dapper SQL. However, I see that I can remove all of that code and just use the `AddTable()` method of `DynamicParameters`:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.AddTable("@balances", "dbo.BalanceType", balances);
```

The problem is that I get an error because my `Balance` class has a non-primitive property: `BalanceGroup`.

Error:

> The type of column 'BalanceGroup' is not supported.

I don't need that property in my Dapper SQL. Can I ignore that property so I can use the above approach instead of having to create a `DataTable`?

I've tried using `Dapper.Contrib` attributes of `[Computed]` and `[Write(false)]` on my object's property, but that didn't work.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43852192/279516

I also tried using `ClassMapper` from `Dapper.Extensions`, but that didn't work either.

Looks like I'll just have to use the `DataTable`.

Final edit: I also tried using `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject`. No dice.

Comment: If all else fails you could always do `balances.Select(b => new { b.Prop1, b.Prop2, ... }` which could be a bit tedious if there are lots of properties, but still. (It also needs to change if you add new properties, but then so does `dbo.BalanceType` so that shouldn't be much of a nuisance).

Comment: That's interesting because, while I don't think I'd want to do that exactly, I could abstract that to a method that uses reflection and adds the properties that don't have my own custom attribute on them.

Comment: I just tried it but it won't compile because an anonymous type can't be used with `DynamicParameters.AddTable()`.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunate. And a bit silly -- I don't see any reason why that shouldn't work since, like, the properties are all there. :P Might be a type accessibility issue for code generation, but now I'm speculating. Personally I'm not a huge fan of TVPs for non-primitive types to begin with, due to the overhead of maintaining them if the schema changes -- all dependent procedures/functions need to be recreated. (For things like list of IDs a generic type with a single `INT` column is fine.) Passing in XML or JSON to be shredded is a slightly less efficient, but also less of a maintenance burden.